# Laravel Homestead setup not quite right?

Tags: laravel-4, vagrant

I installed Laravel Homestead on my Mac, where my Laravel site lives locally at Users/me/Homestead/Site/Laravel. I've been using this to play around and do some real basic introductory testing.

Here is my Homestead.yaml:

```
---
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1

authorize: /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - /Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: /Users/me/Homestead/Site
      to: /home/vagrant/Site

sites:
    - map: homestead.dev
      to: /home/vagrant/Site/Laravel/public

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local
```

First of all, homestead.dev doesn't work. I can access the site at localhost:8000. But I'd like to get the vanity URL working locally... otherwise what's the point of having it in there...

Secondly, I'd like to change the Site folder's name to www, just for kicks. Can I do that and then just change its paths in my Homestead.yaml and everything will just fall into place? Can I do this while vagrant is up or should I make Homestead.yaml edits with it halted or suspended..?

Last but not least I want to add a second site, so within www (or Site currently), another folder, containing another Laravel project/site. In that case do I just add a second mapping under sites in Homestead.yaml? Again, does this edit have to be done with the VM halted?

How do I go about doing all this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the homesteam.dev, I suggest you ping it and make sure you have a response from localhost 127.0.0.1. To be sure that it's working and you successufully added `127.0.0.1 homestead`.app to your `/etc/hosts file`

Comment: I added a new mapping but localhost:8000 still just shows my original Laravel site... obviously... since the mapping isn't working anyway... How's it even know to show my Laravel/public though? Why not project2/public?

Comment: Thanks Amin... Wasn't in my hosts... doy...

Comment: But ok still how do I add a second site?

Comment: it should know because of your configurations `map: homestead.de to: /home/vagrant/Site/Laravel/public` you can setup multiple sites as well

Comment: I added a mapping from project2.dev to /home/vagrant/Site/Laravel/public in my hosts file too and project2.dev:8000 still gives me my original Laravel site.

Comment: change this ` /home/vagrant/Site/Laravel/public` to your new project path

Comment: also I suggest this link ['homstead yaml'](http://laravel.io/forum/05-16-2014-homestead-yaml-folder-mapping)

Comment: Got it! Had to `vagrant reload --provision`. phew